# How to read the registers of a QEMU VM with KVM enabled?

Tags: qemu, kvm

I'm trying to sample the EIP register of a QEMU virtual machine at random times.
For that, I created a thread inside QEMU that performs:

```
CPUState* cpu=/*code for choosing a random virtual cpu*/;
X86CPU *x86cpu = X86_CPU(cpu);
CPUX86State *env = &x86cpu->env;
while(true){
    waittime=(rand()%50000);
    usleep(waittime);
    eip = env->eip;
    printf("EIP= %zu\n",eip);
}
```

However, it always outputs the same value!

On the other hand - if I disable KVM - it perfectly prints various values... But I really need KVM working...

How can I do it with KVM working?

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable about Qemu, code, but shouldn't `X86CPU *x86cpu = X86_CPU(cpu);` read `X86CPU *x86cpu = (X86_CPU*)cpu;`? You might simply be reading from a random address in your process space.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No -  my code is fine. I performed a sanity check by breakpointing my VM (i.e. I put the breakpoint at the source code of the kernel that QEMU runs runs) with gdb.  Both my code an gdb gave me the same address.

Comment: ah! I was missing the `_` between `X86` and `CPU`; tricky :)

Comment: haha yeah... its a macro :) not casting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the answer so I'm posting here for others:

Following [this discussion](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/185348/), I figured out that in order to read the register values, one must synchronize the KVM state with QEMU. So, before reading the registers, a call to `kvm-all.c:kvm_cpu_synchronize_state()` is required.

Without it, you will just read stale values.